# Devise with LDAP auth problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ldap

I'm currently trying to implement Devise with LDAP Authentication on RAILS3. I've got it setup and it appears to connect and try to auth, but appears to fail. I don't seem to get any sort of real error messages to work with so its very difficult to take it any further.

**Log of login session:**

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 192.168.160.1 at Tue Dec 06 05:20:16 +0000 2011
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Sign in", "authenticity_token"=>"G2tEq9gPpJiN0RhanTd8HMWno62F+1oLWbU4xdX78bg=", "utf8"=>"\342\234\223", "user"=>{"remember_me"=>"0", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "login"=>"richmond@email.com"}}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`login` = 'richmond@email.com' LIMIT 1
  LDAP: LDAP dn lookup: mail=richmond@email.com
  LDAP: LDAP search for login: mail=richmond@email.com
  LDAP: Authorizing user mail=richmond@email.com,ou=groupxx,o=company.com
  LDAP: LDAP dn lookup: mail=richmond@email.com
  LDAP: LDAP search for login: mail=richmond@email.com
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 7147ms
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Sign in", "authenticity_token"=>"G2tEq9gPpJiN0RhanTd8HMWno62F+1oLWbU4xdX78bg=", "utf8"=>"\342\234\223", "user"=>{"remember_me"=>"0", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "login"=>"richmond@email.com"}}
Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (0.1ms)
Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 23ms (Views: 21.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/defaults.js" for 192.168.160.1 at Tue Dec 06 05:20:23 +0000 2011
Served asset /defaults.js - 404 Not Found (3ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/defaults.js"):


Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.5ms)
```

**ldap config:**

```
development:
  host: ldap.company.com
  port: 636
  attribute: mail
  base: ou=groupxx,o=company.com
  #admin_user: cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com
  #admin_password: admin_password
  ssl: true
  # <<: *AUTHORIZATIONS
```

I don't have access to the LDAP server so I cannot confirm anything from that end. The main issue I have is that I cannot get any error messages out of the login process - Is it not able to find the user? Does it find the user but fail login? Why does it do 2 LDAP searches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the problem I had was that the LDAP server my company (IBM) uses was using a different protocol standard to the ones officially supported by NET-LDAP.
You simply need to change the PagedResults Control Type to a slightly different standard:

```
#PagedResults = "1.2.840.113556.1.4.319" # Microsoft evil from RFC 2696
PagedResults = "2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.2" # IBM Bluepages compatible ControlType
```

[Full code change details here.](https://github.com/strich/ruby-net-ldap/commit/0ce9568f255743b7e9b58a3f7f2a1fc0081bd89e)

I forked it and fixed it over [here on GitHub.](https://github.com/strich/ruby-net-ldap)

Comment: Can you give more detail on what you changed? I am having a very similar problem and I wonder if I can fix it by using your solution somehow.

Answer (score 4):

same issue here. Did a ldapsearch, which works however. Company is running an ActiveDirectory server here:

```
ldapsearch -Z -h ldap.company.com -p 389 -s sub -D
"cn=somebody,ou=my_ou,dc=ldap,dc=company,dc=com" -W -b
"dc=ldap,dc=company,dc=com" "(&(cn=somebody))" mail
```

**Solution:**

I have found the solution: In `config/initializers/devise.rb` I missed to activate `config.ldap_use_admin_to_bind = true`. Only with this flag, devise_ldap_authenticatable really uses the BindDN (i.e. admin_user, admin_password which both have to be uncommented) defined at `config/ldap.yml`.

Comment: Except I don't have an LDAP admin user/pass. I believe our LDAP server uses anon bind.

Answer (score 0):

I did encounter the same problem on my ActiveDirectory. I tried using the bind user but it didn´t help either. I changed devise according to screencast 210 to use the username field. Here´s my ldap.yml

```
  development:
  host: dcburda0
  port: 636
  attribute: cn
  base: OU=Organisation,DC=mydomain,DC=com
  admin_user: CN=username,OU=Support Center Muenchen,OU=name GmbH,OU=Organisation,DC=mydomain,DC=com
  admin_password: password
  ssl: true
```

Comment: The accepted answer was posted one day after the answer you're commenting on. ;-)